# Which is the relation between between population/probability space/sampling?

Tags: estimation, sampling, parameter-estimation, sampling-theory

I am trying to understand the relation between population/probability space/sampling in Econometrics. My arguments are divided in 3 sub-questions which trace my attempt to link in a logical way the three concepts.

---

Consider a target population of individuals; for each individual in this population we believe that $$income=beta*education+u$$

where $income, education, u$ are real numbers. $u$ collects all the variables affecting income in addition to education.

We are interested in learning about $\beta$.

---

**Sub-question 1:** Imagine to extract at random an individual $m$ from the population and observe her income, education, and additional features (denoted by the random variables $Y_m, X_m, U_m$). Intuitively, I understand why we can say that the income, education, additional features of the extracted individual are random variables: we don't know a priori which individual will be picked from the urn representing the whole population and, hence, we attach a probability to each potential outcome. More formally, to define a random variable we need a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, Pr)$. Is $\Omega$ set equal to the population?

---

**Sub-question 2:** If the answer to question 1 is YES, then, if we knew the entire population (i.e, if we knew $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, Pr)$) and suppose $E(X_m^2)\neq 0$ and $E(X_mU_m)=0$, we could easily compute the exact value of $\beta$ as
$$
\beta=E(Y_mX_m)/E(X_m^2)
$$
Correct?

---

**Sub-question 3:** The problem is that we don't know the entire population (i.e, we don't know $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, Pr)$) and so we try to  approximate in some good way  $E(Y_mX_m)$ and $E(X_m^2)$ by appropriately taking a subset of the whole population (sampling). For example, a way to appropriately take a subset of the whole population is the following: for $m=1,...,M$:

- We draw at random an individual from the urn containing the entire population, we label him/her with the index $m$, and we register his/her income and education level (denoted by the random variables $Y_m, X_m)$. The additional features affecting income remain unobserved (denoted by the random variables $U_m$).
- We put back in the urn individual $m$.

The sampling scheme just described implies that
$$
(i) \hspace{1cm}\{Y_m, X_m, U_m\}_{m=1}^M \text{ are i.i.d. across $m$}
$$

We then define
$$
\hat{\beta}=\frac{\frac{1}{M}\sum_{m=1}^MY_mX_m}{\frac{1}{M}\sum_{m=1}^M X_m^2}
$$
By $(i)$, $\frac{1}{M}\sum_{m=1}^MY_mX_m\rightarrow_p E(Y_mX_m)$ and $\frac{1}{M}\sum_{m=1}^M X_m^2\rightarrow_p E(X^2_m)$.

Hence,
$$
\hat{\beta}\rightarrow_p \beta
$$ 
Correct?

---

**Sub-question 4**: Suppose also that $U_m$ is a continuous random variable. Does this implicitly imply stating that the population is very large or a continuum or infinite?

Comment: You have to be careful when you talk about so called 'continuity' of a random variable. You may not even have a topology on $\Omega$, what continuity do we mean, exactly?

Comment: @AlvinLepik Thanks, I am very confused and I would appreciate if you could post an answer specifying the parts where my arguments are weak or do not make sense.

Comment: Maybe a better claim is "If $U_m$ has strictly positive density on $\mathbb{R}$, then we can say that the population is large"? But, again, I am very confused: what is the relation between $\Omega$ and the assumptions we make on the probability distribution of $U_m$?